# MYSQL to DB2 sql

Tags: mysql, sql, function, db2

Need some help to convert below MYSQL query to DB2 query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(count_datetime))/300)*300) AS t,
sum(count_web) as web,
sum(count_mobile) as mobile,
sum(count_total) as total 
from clicks_user_count GROUP BY t  
ORDER BY `t`  DESC
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: I'm having difficulties to convert the MYSQl sql to DB2 sql. For example which function in DB2 is similar with MYSQL FROM_UNIXTIME function?

Comment: Why are there two columns being named "web"?

Comment: i already corrected the 2nd alias which should be mobile. Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FROM_UNIXTIME (P_UTS BIGINT)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
RETURN TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01-00.00.00') + CURRENT TIMEZONE + P_UTS SECONDS;
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks that's the equivalent to your query

```
SELECT
  timestamp(date(count_datetime)) + (midnight_seconds(count_datetime) / 300 * 300) seconds AS t,
  sum(count_web) as web,
  sum(count_mobile) as mobile,
  sum(count_total) as total
from clicks_user_count
GROUP BY timestamp(date(count_datetime)) + (midnight_seconds(count_datetime) / 300 * 300) seconds
order by t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot nfgl. Now I'm able to to reproduce the same result in DB2 : )

Answer (score 0):

Below SQL assisted by nfgl able to produce same result in DB2. Thx you.

SELECT
  timestamp(date(count_datetime)) + (midnight_seconds(count_datetime) / 300 * 300) seconds AS t,
  sum(count_web) as web,
  sum(count_mobile) as mobile,
  sum(count_total) as total
from clicks_user_count
GROUP BY timestamp(date(count_datetime)) + (midnight_seconds(count_datetime) / 300 * 300) seconds
order by t